# Differences between smart contracts licenses. No License (None) vs The Unlicense (Unlicense)

Tags: solidity

I want to verify a smart contract in Etherscan.
The site request to me the contract license from a list, but my contract is over other different license that is not listed.

What opcion would be better for my case? **No License (None)** or **The Unlicense (Unlicense)?**

Thank you

1. No License (None)
2. The Unlicense (Unlicense)
3. MIT License (MIT)
4. GNU General Public License v2.0 (GNU GPLv2)
5. GNU General Public License v3.0 (GNU GPLv3)
6. GNU Lesser General Public License v2.1 (GNU LGPLv2.1)
7. GNU Lesser General Public License v3.0 (GNU LGPLv3)
8. BSD 2-clause Simplified license (BSD-2-Clause)
9. BSD 3-clause New Or Revised license (BSD-3-Clause)
10. Mozilla Public License 2.0 (MPL-2.0)
11. Open Software License 3.0 (OSL-3.0)
12. Apache 2.0 (Apache-2.0) 13) GNU Affero General Public License (GNU AGPLv3)

Comment: Hope the following helps: https://etherscan.io/contract-license-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No License (None):** It protect you code if you need to license it in the future.

**The Unlicense (Unlicense):** Indicates that your code not have any protection. Its totally open and free for any use and modification.